# to get nth highest salary from a table there is a code which i dont understand

Tags: mysql, sql

1. first of all i cant understand how a.salary <= b.salary internally works. if worker a and worker b are clones then how is >= computed internally and if the sign is changed to <,>,= HOW is it working?
2. COUNT(distinct salary)  should just give a number so if there are 3 distinct salaries there should be value 3 for it. if I execute it without the 'where' condition then  it does'nt show any result.
3. how does the 'where 1=' actually work? it shows different result for 2>=,3>= etc.

there are other methods to find the nth highest salary but i need to understand this one

```
select distinct salary
from worker a
where 1 = (select COUNT(distinct salary) from worker b where a.salary >= b.salary)
```

Comment: This is basic math. If a.Salary is `100`, and b.Salary is `101`, then `a.Salary >= b.Salary` is false (`100` is not greater than or equal to `101`), and `a.Salary <= b.Salary` is true (`100` is less than or equal to `101`, because it's less than). I don't know what the rest of your text means. If you have the two salaries I described earlier, then `COUNT(distinct salary)` will return `2`, because there are two distinct salaries (`100` and `101`). If we add a salary of `101` for employee `c`, then `COUNT(distinct salary)` would still be two, because `101` and `100` are the only distinct ones.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this table:

```
create table worker(name varchar(10), salary int);
insert into worker(name, salary) values
('Alice', 500),('Bob', 400),('John', 500),('Nick', 400),('Mary', 300),('Jill', 300);
```

And these queries with the corresponding results:

```
select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where salary >= 500
| counter |
|       1 |

select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where salary >= 400
| counter |
|       2 |

select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where salary >= 300
| counter |
|       3 |
```

What these queries do is return the number of **distinct** salaries that are `greater or equal` than a certain amount.
So if there is a `salary = 500` since the result of the 1st query is `1` this means that there isn't any salary greater than this, so this is the max salary because the number of **distinct** salaries that are `greater or equal` to that salary is `1`.
 
The 2nd query's result is `2` and this means that there is only 1 distinct salary greater than `400`, so this the 2nd greater salary of all.

Now consider the same queries with the reverse inequality sign:

```
select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where 300 >= salary
| counter |
|       1 |

select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where 400 >= salary
| counter |
|       2 |

select count(distinct salary) counter from worker where 500 >= salary 
| counter |
|       3 |
```

the 1st query returns the minimum salary because the number of distinct salaries that are less or equal than `300` is 1, and so on.
This is what your code does: it finds the **minimum** and **not** the maximum salary.
If you want the max salary you must write the code like this:

```
select distinct salary
from worker a
where 1 = (select COUNT(distinct salary) from worker b where b.salary >= a.salary)
```

If you want the 2nd highest salary you must write the code like this:

```
select distinct salary
from worker a
where 2 = (select COUNT(distinct salary) from worker b where b.salary >= a.salary)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3564596d08445ecf87a3378fb794d93b).

Comment: if the table has first_name monika | nihanta | amitabh salary:10000 | 8000 | 50000, then when we use b.salary>=a.salary . how is comparison done in the two attributes? does it  give out every salary of worker b where a.salary>=b.salary. if so then the salaries in the two tables would be equal atleast once so this would always result in with all salaries of the worker b coming.?

Comment: There is only 1 table with 2 aliases a and b. The code compares each salary with all the salaries of the table (including itself).

Comment: does that mean a.salary>=b.salary having values of salary as 500,100,80 would compare first 500 to 500,100 and then 80.after that 100 and 80 would be compared to every other salary in the table. BUT thats the confusion...because of '=' there would come all 3 salaries and if one salary come multiple times then count(distinct salary ) would take only distinct values which would still be 3. how is a.salary>=b.salary actually performed?

Comment: For 500 the condition salary >= 500 will occur only once, so the result will be 1 (the highest salary). For 100 the condition salary >= 100 will occur twice, so the result will be 2 (the 2nd highest salary). For 80 the condition salary >= 80 will occur 3 times, so the result will be 3 (the 3d highest salary).